# React lazy load dynamic import load component on Click of a button

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading, dynamic-import

I am using code splitting for my enterprise application as I want the first time user experience to be seamless. I bumped into an issue where I want to PRTEFETCH a Component (Page 2) before it can be displayed. Example: I am on Home Page -> Then I click Page 1 LINK which has the Page 2 Link.

My requirement is that I want to PREFETCH Page 2 Component when I land on Page 1, but what I observed is that the Code I wrote in Page 1 as below for prefetching Page 2 is getting loaded when I load the site i.e. when Home Page is loaded.

`const page2ComponentPromise = import("./Page2");
const Page2Component = lazy(() => page2ComponentPromise);`

My questions are as follows :

1. Is webpack doing this in the background ? I think it is.
2. Can we control this behavior and instruct webpack when to START PREFETCHING as I would like to take
   this approach for intuitive paths in my web app ? How ?
3. Have I done something wrong ?
4. Is my query valid ? Meaning can we achieve this behavior and how ?

Please guide me through some reference URL's. Thanks !

Comment: Maybe this answer help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58687397/react-lazy-and-prefetching-components/58688377#58688377

Comment: Thanks @YashJoshi it did help. Late post.

Answer (score 0):

this [article](https://medium.com/hackernoon/lazy-loading-and-preloading-components-in-react-16-6-804de091c82d) explained how lazy loading works and how to implement eager loading. I hope it will help you as well.