# React Code Splitting - Load other component after initial page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, optimization, lazy-loading, code-splitting

I just implemented Router-based code splitting (lazy load) in my app. AFAIK, when lazy load is implemented, a user visiting a page will only load a certain chunk of the whole bundle and nothing else.

So, is there a way where we can tell React to begin loading the other component *after* the initial page is loaded, so that the user don't have to wait when they jump to another page?

```js
const App = React.lazy(() => import('./components/home/App'))
const Game = React.lazy(() => import('./components/game/Game'))
const Custom = React.lazy(() => import('./components/custom/Custom'))
const Credits = React.lazy(() => import('./components/credits/Credits'))
const Rules = React.lazy(() => import('./components/rules/Rules'))
const NotFound = React.lazy(() => import('./components/404/404'))
```

Comment: maybe this answer help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58687397/react-lazy-and-prefetching-components/58688377#58688377

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [Yash Joshi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9119053/yash-joshi)'s enlightenment, I now realize what I'm trying to do is called "Preloading a component".

```js
// component/home/App.js
// Preloading Game.js from App.js
const lazyWithPreload = (factory) => {
    const Component = React.lazy(factory)
    Component.preload = factory
    return Component
}
 
const Game = lazyWithPreload(() => import('../game/Game'))
 
const App = () => {
    React.useEffect(() => {
        Game.preload()
    }, [])
    return (<div>Something cool</div>)
}
```

`lazyWithPreload` preloads the component whenever and wherever I want, including when the initial page is loaded (which solves my problem).

Source: https://medium.com/hackernoon/lazy-loading-and-preloading-components-in-react-16-6-804de091c82d